# How to find connected components in graph efficiently without adjacency matrix?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, connected-components

I want to find the connected components in an undirected graph. However, I don't have an adjacency matrix. Instead I have a set of vertices as well as a function telling me whether two vertices are adjacent. What is the most efficient way to find all connected components?

I know I could just calculate the entire adjacency matrix and use depth-first search to find all components. But that would not be very efficient as I'd need to check every pair of vertices.

What I'm currently doing is the following procedure:

1. Pick any unassigned vertex which is now its own component
2. Find all neighbors of that vertex and add them to the component
3. Find all neighbors of the just added vertices (amongst those vertices not yet assigned to any component) and add them too
4. Repeat previous step until no new neighbors can be found
5. The component is now complete, repeat from the first step to find other components until all vertices are assigned

This is the pseudocode:

```py
connected_components(vertices):
  // vertices belonging to the current component and whose neighbors have not yet been added
  vertices_to_check= [vertices.pop()]
  // vertices belonging to the current component
  current_component = []
  components = []
  while (vertices.notEmpty() or vertices_to_check.notEmpty()):
    if (vertices_to_check.isEmpty()): // All vertices in the current component have been found
      components.add(current_component)
      current_component = []
      vertices_to_check= [vertices.pop()]
    next_vertex = vertices_to_check.pop()
    current_component.add(next_vertex)
    for vertex in vertices: // Find all neighbors of next_vertex
      if (vertices_adjacent(vertex, next_vertex)):
        vertices.remove(vertex)
        vertices_to_check.add(vertex)
  components.add(current_component)
  return components
```

I understand that this method is faster than calculating the adjacency matrix in most cases, as I don't need to check whether two vertices are adjacent, if it is already known they belong to the same component. But is there a way to improve this algorithm?

Comment: I could use more readable code and a clear example to follow your implementation.  What you describe is the simple Kleene closure of node, which is one description of finding the connected components.  However, your variable names are generic, without specific documentation for either those or the algorithm steps.  You've used `new_vertices` as an array until the last reference, where it appears to be a function.  Is `vertices` the entire list of nodes, or just a set of starting points?

Comment: I edited it now and tried to improve it somewhat. Thank you for noticing the mistake in the usage of `new_vertices`. The variable `vertices` is the set of all nodes.

Comment: it seems like you may get better help posting on [computerscience.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), or - if something is just not working or needs refactor and you're looking for a fresh set of eyes - on [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). also see [this elaborate post on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/183101) on where is best to post algorithm-related questions.

Comment: Re: "The variable `vertices` is the set of all nodes": That's not true; the set of all nodes never changes, but the function removes nodes from `vertices` over time, and it continues running until it's removed *all* nodes from `vertices`. So `vertices` clearly is *not* the set of all nodes.

Comment: Well at the beginning of the algorithm it contains all nodes and it removes them as they are assigned to their corresponding component. Sure I could have made a copy of that set at the beginning of the algorithm, but the actual algorithm wouldn't change.

Comment: @LionelDamtew: I'm not suggesting that you copy the set, I'm just suggesting that you state accurate facts instead of inaccurate ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, any algorithm will have to call `vertices_adjacent` for every single pair of vertices that turn out to belong to separate components, because otherwise it will never be able to verify that there's no link between those components.

Now, if a majority of vertices all belong to a single component, then there may not be too many such pairs; but unless you *expect* a majority of vertices all belong to a single component, there's little point optimizing specifically for that case. So, discarding that case, the very best-case scenario is:

- There turn out to be exactly two components, each with the same number of vertices (½|*V*| each). So there are ¼|*V*|<sup>2</sup> pairs of vertices that belong to separate components, and you need to call `vertices_adjacent` for each of those pairs.
- These two components turn out to be complete, or you turn out to be exceptionally lucky in your choice of edges to check for first, such that you can detect the connected parts by checking just |*V*| − 2 pairs.

. . . which still involves making ¼|*V*|<sup>2</sup> + |*V*| − 2 calls to `vertices_adjacent`. By comparison, the build-an-adjacency-list approach makes ½|*V*|<sup>2</sup> − ½|*V*| calls — which is more than the best-case scenario, but by a factor of less than 2. (And the *worst*-case scenario is simply equivalent to the build-an-adjacency-list approach. That would happen if no component contains more than two vertices, or if the graph is acyclic and you get unlikely in your choice of edges to check for first. Most graphs will be somewhere in between.)

So it's probably not worth trying to optimize too closely for the *exact* minimum number of calls to `vertices_adjacent`.

That said, your approach seems pretty reasonable to me; it doesn't make any calls to `vertices_adjacent` that are clearly unnecessary, so the only improvement would be a probabilistic one, if it could do a better job guessing which calls will turn out to be useful for eliminating later calls.

One possibility: in many graphs, there are some vertices that have a lot of neighbors and some vertices that have relatively few, according to a [power-law distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law). So if you prioritize vertices based on how many neighbors they're already known to have, you may be able to take advantage of that pattern. (I think this is especially likely to be useful if the majority of vertices really *do* all belong to a single component, which is the only case where a better-than-factor-of-2 improvement is even conceivable.) But, you'll have to test to see if it actually makes a difference for the graphs you're interested in.

Comment: First of all thank you a lot for this response. The graphs I'm dealing with do often consist of only a handful of components, sometimes even just one. I will look into, whether its possible to take advantage of the distribution of neighbors, but I'm a bit skeptical it will make a difference.

Comment: @LionelDamtew: You're welcome! By the way, something that might give you more flexibility in your experiments . . . if you use a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to track your components, you can merge them in essentially O(1) time. That means that you don't need to proceed in any particular order -- in particular, you don't need to traverse a whole component at once before trying other vertex-pairs -- as long as you keep track of which vertex-pairs you have and haven't checked yet.